# Python: Iterate through list, output blank to second list to then call in order

Tags: python, list

Thanks for taking the time to help me out. Still a noob when it comes to Python but I'm slowly getting there.

**Backstory:** Basically I'm transferring configuration from a PBX to a CSV file to then migrate to another system.

**Where I'm stuck:** Currently I have a list of both extension numbers and then voice mail configuration. Not every phone has a voice mail email address so currently what I'm doing is comparing the data to see If the current extension has an email associated. Because of the way the data is exported, I'm storing everything to a list and It all needs to line up.

**What I need it to do:** I need the emails to output nicely to a list and have that line up with the extension list. E.g.:

*list_extension_email = [' ', 'test@test', ' ', ' ', 'test2@test']*

*list_extension_numbers = ['1000', '401', '402', '403', '404']*

**Code:**

```
list_extension_voicemail = ['401, test@test', '404, test2@test']
list_extension_numbers = ['1000', '401', '402', '403', '404']
list_extension_email = []
line_variable = 0
blank_voicemails = 0

for extension in list_extension_numbers:
    extension_number = list_extension_numbers[line_variable]
    blank_line = " "
    for extension_voicemail in list_extension_voicemail:
      extension_and_voicemail = extension_voicemail.split(',')
      if extension_and_voicemail[0] in extension_number:
        while blank_voicemails != 0:
          list_extension_email.append(blank_line)
          blank_voicemails-=1
        list_extension_email.append(extension_and_voicemail[1])
        blank_voicemails = 0
      else:
        blank_voicemails+=1


extension_email = list_extension_email[line_variable]
```

**Sorry if this is very vague and non descriptive, I'm open to hearing any solutions. Once again, thanks all**

Comment: I can't quite understand what you want, could you give an example input and output?

Comment: @user5173426, desired output is to turn this:

list_extension_voicemail = ['401, test@test', '404, test2@test']
list_extension_numbers = ['1000', '401', '402', '403', '404']

Into:
list_extension_email = [' ', 'test@test', ' ', ' ', 'test2@test']

list_extension_numbers = ['1000', '401', '402', '403', '404']

Comment: @Nullman, Sample input included in the first two lines of the code, sample output is included under 'what I need it to do', let me know if you need a further explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
list_extension_voicemail = ['401, test@test', '404, test2@test']
list_extension_numbers = ['1000', '401', '402', '403', '404']

# Make list of empty emails
list_extension_email = [''] * len(list_extension_numbers)
# Make a dict that gives you the list index for each number
number_idx = {number: idx for idx, number in enumerate(list_extension_numbers)}
for number_email in list_extension_voicemail:
    # Split by comma
    number, email = number_email.split(',')
    # Remove extra spaces
    number = number.strip()
    email = email.strip()
    # Set email in list if number exists
    if number in number_idx:
        list_extension_email[number_idx[number]] = email

# Print result
print('list_extension_email =', list_extension_email)
print('list_extension_numbers =', list_extension_numbers)
```

Output:

```
list_extension_email = ['', 'test@test', '', '', 'test2@test']
list_extension_numbers = ['1000', '401', '402', '403', '404']
```

Comment: after playing around with it that seems to work! Although I'm a little unsure about what some of the code does, would you care to explain? Specifically:

number_idx = {number: idx for idx, number in enumerate(list_extension_numbers)} 

&

list_extension_email[number_idx[number]] = email

Comment: @Trap If you don't yet have experience with `dict` objects and comprehensions in Python, please go through some book/tutorial/course on the language, as these are pretty fundamental elements that you will need and see regularly. In this case, `number_idx` is a structure that, for every string in `list_extension_numbers`, gives you its index in the list. `number_idx[number]` will then give you that index for the number you got from splitting the string, so `list_extension_email[number_idx[number]] = email` will set the value in that index in `list_extension_email` to the extracted email.